# CC.NET and SVN, enable a setting similar to TortoiseSVN "use-commit-times = yes" in CruiseControl.NET workingDirectory

Tags: svn, configuration, tortoisesvn, cruisecontrol.net

I would like the cc.net workingDirectory to have the files show their commit date.  The "use-commit-times = yes" is from TortoiseSVN settings, and believe that there is a similar setting that I can use in cc.net.

Is this type of setting possible in cc.net?  If so, how?

Update:

What I need help with is how to set this in the ccnet.config file, rather than the SVN files.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261731/how-can-i-import-a-directory-structure-into-svn-keeping-the-file-and-folder-modi

Comment: What I need help with is how to set this in the ccnet.config file, rather than the svn files.

Comment: Sorry, but you can't. This is an svn setting, not ccnet. You can set this for the user you use to run CruiseControl.Net or by registry settings. Look under "Subversion looks for system-wide configuration values under the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Tigris.org\Subversion key" in the http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html Version Control with Subversion book. Again, this is explained in the question linked as duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.